# How and where does tomcat store the files that are created on dotCMS in the computer?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, server, storage, dotcms

I am new to dotCMS. I am looking for the location that tomcat stores the data or files that are created by user, such as the content and site.

I created the the site and some content on dotCMS, and I used tomcat as the server. I am finding the location that those data or file saves in the computer, and that should be inside the server.

Someone told me that those .jsp files store in

```
tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp
```

will tell the location of the data, and I can trace the location with the help of cmd. But I have no idea what the codes inside the .jsp is talking about.

Could anyone please teach me how to trace the location of those data? How dotCMS processes those data and then send to the server for storage?

Thanks!

--------update--------
Is that means file based assets inside the site will store in the same folder? How about the storage location of a site? Is that and specific file to store one site, or the sites will be group together in a file? May I have one more question: The characteristic of dotCMS is to manage and process data in a website and maintain them in a user-friendly way? Those data will be store in the server. I would like to confirm whether it is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Note that this really has nothing to do with Tomcat. It's all about where dotCMS stores its stuff. Doesn't dotCMS use a database for storage?

Comment: I found that there is a inode for every site or content etc. which is unique. I search the inode in the whole folder that I downloaded from dotCMS. The folder that has the same name (inode) located inside the tomcat asset folder. That's why I have this guess. I am sorry for misleading you. The tomcat should do nothing about processing the data. But tomcat maybe a place for storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dotCMS stores the site and content of a site two ways.  File based assets, like images,css, video are stored under the /assets folder in a b-tree like structure based on the asset version uuid.  So if I had an image that had a version id (inode) of 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000 then that would be found under:

```
/assets/1/2/123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000/fileAsset/here-is-your-image.jpg
```

Content and structure, such as a wysiwyg content or hosts/folders are stored in the database and mapped at runtime to specific urls.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is that means file based assets inside the site will store in the same folder? How about the storage location of a site? May I have one more question: The characteristic of dotCMS is to manage and process data in a website and maintain them in a user-friendly way? Those data will be store in the server. I would like to confirm whether it is correct. Thanks.